# decomposition of general unitary

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Does anybody know how to prove the following:
Given a unitary matrix $U$, prove that:
$$U = V \sigma_x V^\dagger W \sigma_x W^\dagger$$

For the proper $V$ and $W$.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $\sigma_x$?

Comment: @RobertLewis Presumably they're referring to the [Pauli matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)
$$
\sigma_x = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$

Comment: If I have interpreted your question correctly, I think this is possible if and only if $U$ is unitary with determinant $1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom;  so either $U$ is of size $2$ or $V, W$ are $n \times 2$?

Comment: @RobertLewis I think $U$ is of size $2$